# I get the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when trying to request something that is in square brackets

Tags: python, string, python-requests, integer, typeerror

I get this error (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str) when trying to request something in square brackets. I've searched on this website and other ones a lot. I've tried [0]. The real problem is that `["data"]` and `["fortnite"]` are not in square brackets, `["posts"]` opens the square brackets and `["title"]`, `["description"]`, `["author"]` and `["url"]` are in the square brackets.

```
compareblog = requests.get("https://fn-api.com/api/blogposts")
    comparename = compareblog.json()["data"]["fortnite"]["posts"]["title"]

    count = 1
    initialcheckdelay = 3
    checkdelayafter = 60
    while 1:
      print(f'Waiting for blog changes -> [Count: {count}]\n')
    blog = requests.get("https://fn-api.com/api/blogposts")
    yesyes = [int(blog.json())]
    name = yesyes["data"]["fortnite"]["posts"]["title"]
    desc = yesyes["data"]["fortnite"]["posts"]["description"]
    author = yesyes["data"]["fortnite"]["posts"]["author"]
    link = yesyes["data"]["fortnite"]["posts"]["url"]
    time.sleep(initialcheckdelay)
    count = count + 1
    if comparename != name:
      while 2:
        print(f"Blog change detected!")
        api.update_status(f"New Blog Post has been detected by {author}!\n\n{name}\n{desc}\nLink: {link}") #This is a Tweet
        sleep(checkdelayafter)
```

This is the error I get after running this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File {filename}, line 114, in <module>
    blog_check()
  File {filename}, line 77, in blog_check
    comparename = compareblog.json()["data"]["fortnite"]["posts"]["title"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `'posts'` is a list of dicts. Each of those dicts contain a key, `'title'`. To retrieve the value of a title, you need to select an individual post from the `posts` list.

```py
posts = compareblog.json()["data"]["fortnite"]["posts"]
first_post = posts[0]
title = first_post["title"]
```